# how to update a record in sqlite proxy store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am using SQLite proxy for my sencha app to make the app offline. can someone tell me how to update a record in the store. I tried store.set('filed', value), but it didn't worked.

here is the code I am using..

```
Ext.getStore('Team').each(function(record) {
        if(record.get('race_id') == raceId && record.get('round') == round) {
            record.set('start_position', startPosition);
        }
    });
Ext.getStore('Team').sync();
```

I am refering [this](https://github.com/shepsii/SQLite-Proxy-ST2) for implementing the SqlLite-proxy.

Answer (score 0):

first of all set method is not for store this method is of record and you have to sync store after update record for final change in localstorage like  `

```
record.set('field',value); 
store.sync();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.. I used the above code but now I am getting this error ... undefined----could not execute statement due to a constaint failure (19 constraint failed)

Comment: I think note.set('start_position', startPosition); this line should be record.set('start_position', startPosition); AND proxy type is "localstorage"

Comment: Sorry... that's by mistake.. but still have same problem... can you please refer me some other source or example of SQLite proxy implementation.